# Did everything to optimise SEO ranking of site but the site does not show up

Tags: seo, search-engines

I have created a business [website](https://www.progressiveopt.com) for a client of mine. The client runs a business of providing therapeutic and behavioral services to youth and families experiencing developmental, emotional, and behavioral challenges.

The company is called Progressive Option Support Services. The client wanted to optimize the website so it can show up in the top of google search results when you search for "progressive option support services". I have no previous experience in SEO so I followed few blogs and articles on how I can improve the search ranking of the site and implemented it. Some of the things I did were:

1. Using h1 tag in the website
2. Giving a proper meta description, title etc for the site
3. Making sure there are no broken links.
4. Giving a proper value to the alt attribute of an html image element.
5. Creating a sitemap.xml and submitting it to google search console.
6. Creating a robots.txt file.
7. Making sure there are no canonicalization issues with the site.
8. Using the keywords the client wants to associate with the business on the site and meta description.

However when the client searches for "progressive option support services" the first result she gets is the website for Progressive Insurance. It's not a sponsored advertisement, its the actual progressive insurance website.

However if you google "progressive leasing", you will see the following search result:

[image]

So it makes me think that whatever SEO optimisation I did for the site is not working. When I google "progressive option support services" on my browser I see the site I created.

[image]

So I do not know why the client see's Progressive Insurance website in the top of the search result whereas I see the actual website. The client and I are in different geographical regions (New Jersey, USA and Mumbai, India), so maybe that might be the deciding factor on why she sees the insurance company and I don't. But by that logic when she searches "progressive leasing" - she sees the result for progressive leasing (the first image).

Another question I had was how can I show my search result the way Progressive Leasing shows up, i.e the sitmap below the search result?

Here is the github link of the website code: https://github.com/neeraj87/poss-website.git

Any suggestions and/or modifications which will help the site show up will be very appreciated.

Thank you all.

Comment: Welcome to Webmasters Stack Exchange! It is usually best practice to ask questions separately. This makes it more likely for volunteers who can only answer one part of the question to answer the question. Individual questions can also be more accurately tagged.

Answer (score 2):

For consistency when checking Google search engine results, ensure you are logged out of all Google accounts. Click on "Settings" in search results and choose a target region if it is different to your current region. This will give the most consistent results between yourself and your client although maybe not exactly the same.

Two things which might improve search engine result positions:

1. add key search terms to the start of Page Titles
2. allow enough time for Google to search and re-index all the pages on the website (this could take a week or more)

You might also consider including some local information such as a town, city, state or other place name in the page titles, headings, and meta data which should help locals find the business unless the client is aiming for a national or international audience.

Website owners have little or no control over the sitelinks under the main search result for the website but achieving the top search result for your website name and having a clear navigation system that Google understands seems to help.

Comment: Thanks Neil, I will look into this solution.